# This is the result I get when trying to install pip3

Tags: python

This is the result I get when trying to install pip3.

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-session-common : Breaks: eog (< 3.36.0) but 3.26.1-1 is to be installed
 kali-menu : Breaks: python-faraday (< 3.10.0)
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: What is your OS, and what version?

Comment: Linux zlatan 4.13.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.13.10-1kali2 (2017-11-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by an incomplete package installation.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then run the install command again.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```